# Changing font color dynamically within script

Tags: fonts

Any ideas how to change the font color of the linked text in the resulting row?  Unlinked text goes from black to white, but linked text in highlighted row stays black.  Need it to go white as well.

```
var INTENDED_MONTH = 7 //August
// INTENDED_MONTH is zero-relative
now = new Date().getDate(),
rows = document.getElementById('scripture').rows;
if (new Date().getMonth() != INTENDED_MONTH) {
    // need a value here less than 1, or the box for the first of the month will be in Red
    now = 0.5
};
for (var i = 0, rl = rows.length; i < rl; i++) {
    var cells = rows[i].childNodes;
    for (j = 0, cl = cells.length; j < cl; j++) {
        if (cells[j].nodeName == 'TD'
  && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue != ''
  && cells[j].firstChild.nodeValue == now) {
            rows[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red' // 'ffff99' // '#ffd700' // TODAY - red
            rows[i].style.color = 'white'
      $('html,body').delay(500).animate({scrollTop:rows[i].offsetTop}, 2000);
        }
    }
}​
```

Comment: you can do that in javascript/jquery.

Comment: Using rows[i].style.color = 'white' to make text white.  How would I change this to make linked text white?

Comment: If "style.color" changes the regular text color, what will change text color when there is an underlying hyperlink, in this specific code?  Thanks.

Comment: you can change the hyperlink color and it should work.  You need to set the css using javascript/jquery.

Comment: The command for changing text color is style.color.  The command to change a cell's background color is style.background.color.  What I need to know is the command to change the color of text that has a link.  Can anyone else help me please? Thanks.